# Why the tax on stocks dividends differs between the types of companies?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, dividends, withholding

Why some types of companies, like a limited partnership LP deduct more percentage on the dividends (for me it was 37%) than the regular percentage (30% for inc,lmt for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, such a question ("why the tax code is just so") is a politics question as historically all dividends were ordinary income in the United States for the periods 1936-1939 and 1954-2003; one might ask instead why corporate dividends became privileged after 49 years without a change.

That said there is a rationale.  As a "partnership" the [entity does not pay taxes](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/mlp.asp) itself.

> They combine the tax benefits of a private partnership—profits are taxed only when investors receive distributions—with the liquidity of a publicly traded company.

In addition to MLPs this is also a defining feature of REITs and a few other types of entity.

The difference with corporation dividends is there are two points at which taxes are assessed: the corporation pays tax on income paid by the corporation, and then any dividend to investors is investment income paid by the investor.

I presume the capitalists who chose between a partnership organization and a corporate organization assessed that the total tax impact on the cash flow of a dollar of income at the entity all the way to usable cash in hand of an investor would be taxed in total lower in a partnership (for at least for some investors).

Comment: are there a list for dividends tax percentage by company type? because I want to know how much percentage will be deducted before investing in a high-dividends stocks (I'm not from us)

Comment: or this is just related to S or C corporation? so in my case all the companies' dividends will be either 30% or 37%

Comment: @huab As far I can know foreign citizens are paying taxes according to Agreement between their country and US. For example US->UA = 15%